# How do I get my prev/next links to send me to the top of the page?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a javascript pagination div that I found on dynamicdrive.com, so I've been cut and pasting - I'm no javascript junkie, far from it! Right now, I have a pagination bar at the top of the article and one at the bottom, but when I use the one at the bottom, it sends me to the bottom of the next page, instead of the top. So I click next and then have to scroll up - is there a way I can tweak this so that it sends me directly to the top of the next page?

This is the pagination version I'm using - it's Demo 3 on: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex17/virtualpagination.htm

Thanks in advance for any tips you can give me!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is a way to do this using the virtualpagination.js library.  You should be able to wrap the library's main `navigate` function with your own funciton that will bring the scroll back to the top.

Try putting this in a javascript file, and including it *after* the `virtualpaginate.js` file:

```
virtualpaginate.prototype._navigate = virtualpaginate.prototype.navigate;
virtualpaginate.prototype.navigate = function (keyword) {
  window.location = '#wrapperDivId';
  this._navigate(keyword);
}
```

And then wrap your pagination content in a div like so:

```
<div id="wrapperDivId">
  ... your content here ...
</div>
```